# HTML5 canvas alternative to putImageData

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

is there another method to copy region of pixels from (let say) Canvas A to canvas B other than using respectively `getImageData` and `putImageData`.

also, when copy to Canvas B it should be rounded like a paint brush not rectangle.

Comment: Yes you can certainly use canvas.drawImage(..), with eventually canvas.setTransform(..) and define canvas.clip() for rounded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To copy content from one canvas to another you can use `drawImage()`. This method can take image, canvas or video as image source.

To draw rounded there are two ways:

### Method A - Use composite mode

This method assumes the target canvas is empty. First set up a circle on target canvas (`ctx` being context for canvas B/target/destination):

```
ctx.beginPath();                              // clear previous path (if any)
ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 6.283);  // 1) draw a full arc on target
ctx.fill();                                   // fill with default color
```

<sup>1) 6.283 = 2 x PI</sup>

This will draw a circle and fill it (make sure alpha channel is set to full). Then change [composite mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/canvas-tutorial/6_1_canvas_composite.html) and draw in canvas A:

```
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';   // change comp. mode
ctx.drawImage(canvasA, 0, 0);                 // draw canvas A
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over'; // reset to default
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/pm8YW/)**

### Method B - Use clipping

This is similar to method A but target canvas may contain data. The cons with this method is that some browsers will leave a rough (aliased) edge. The basis is similar - first define a full arc as path but don't fill it:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.save();                                   // for removing clip later
ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 6.283);  // draw a full arc on target
ctx.clip();                                   // define clip

ctx.drawImage(canvasA, 0, 0);                 // draw canvas A
ctx.restore();                                // remove clip
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/xXye6/)**

If you want to change the size and position of canvas A when drawn to canvas B then look at the [documentation for `drawImage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975414%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to see the options it comes with.

Comment: Thank you very much..i'll give it a try tomorrow. thanks again