# How to add an image in HTML5 Ball Pool

Tags: html, image, html5-canvas

As topic, how can i add an image in the web page be the one of these ball

And crop the image to be circle like the profile picture of Instagram

Demo: [Ball Pool - Mr.doob](http://www.mrdoob.com/projects/chromeexperiments/ball-pool/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 canvas alternative to putImageData](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23559848/html5-canvas-alternative-to-putimagedata)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use `context.clip` to accomplish clipping an image within a circle**

`context.clip()` creates a clipping path where any new drawings will only be drawn only inside the defined path.  Any drawings that fall outside the clipping path will not show.

Here's how:

1. Define an circular path.
2. Create a clipping path from the circular path.
3. Draw the image and it will be clipped within the circular clipping region.

Illustrating code:

```
// define a path

context.beginPath();
context.arc(100,100,75,0,Math.PI*2);
context.closePath();
context.stroke();  // the stroke is optional


// clip new drawings within this path

context.clip();


// draw the image

// Note: adjust the x,y of drawImage to "frame" your image as desired

context.drawImage(anyImageObject,100-75,100-75);
```

Here's an example of an image clipped inside an animated circle:

http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/255JU/

Example code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    // ball related variables
    var x=50;
    var y=100;
    directionX=3;
    directionY=2;
    var radius=32;
    var offsetX=-37;
    var offsetY=-34;
    var angle=0;

    // the image to be clipped inside the ball
    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=start;
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/facesSmall.png";
    function start(){

        // start the animation
        animate();

    }


    function drawBall(x,y,radius,img,imgOffsetX,imgOffsetY,radianAngle){

        // create a stroked circle at x,y and rotated by radianAngle
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.translate(x,y);
        ctx.rotate(radianAngle);
        ctx.arc(0,0,radius,0,Math.PI*2);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();

        // make the circle a clipping region
        ctx.clip();

        // draw the image into the clipping region
        // (only part of the image will show--the part inside the circle
        ctx.drawImage(img,imgOffsetX,imgOffsetY);

        // restore the context to its original untranslated/unrotated state
        ctx.restore();

    }


    function animate(){

        // request another animation frame
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        // clear the canvas
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

        // draw the ball
        drawBall(x,y,radius,img,offsetX,offsetY,angle);

        // increment the x,y position of the ball
        x+=directionX;
        if(x<radius || x>canvas.width-radius){directionX*=-1; x+=directionX;} 

        y+=directionY;
        if(y<radius || y>canvas.height-radius){directionY*=-1; y+=directionY;} 

        // increment the angle of the ball
        angle+=Math.PI/90;

    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Animated ball with image clipped inside</p>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
    <p>The original image is below</p>
    <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/facesSmall.png">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why i can't rotate all of the ball?

createInstructions2() is modifies
http://jsfiddle.net/losiuhoi/5SzNZ/1/

*if you can't see the image, please run a few times

Comment: Rotate?  Your question asks how to put an image into a circle?

Comment: sorry, just added incomplete comment accidentally

Comment: To rotate a circle you (1) context.save (2) context.translate to the circles center (3) context.rotate to your desired radian angle (4) draw the circle similar to my answer--remember that you're already at the circle's center (5) context.restore.

Comment: Sorry, I express too bad. I mean i can rotate in the web page like this http://www.mrdoob.com/projects/chromeexperiments/ball-pool/ 
http://s276.photobucket.com/user/losiuhoieric/media/2014-05-13_111457.png.html

Comment: I've added a demonstration to my answer.

Comment: I have using your code to clipped an image, but my code have bug, it can't rotate naturally. like the demo(Ball Pool - Mr.doob)

Comment: You can use the code in my answer to apply a "skin" to the object that box2d creates and controls.  Box2d is a fantastic physics library and I encourage you to learn it.  However, detailed instructions on how to use it is too broad for a Stackoverflow question (SO questions should be specific).  Good luck with your project!